# RSpec testing a destroy action with a conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test a destroy action that has a conditional, it works fine if I just call the business without params like that:

```
def destroy
    if @message_rule.destroy
      Messages::Reclassifier.call
    end
```

But if I do it like that:

```
def destroy
    if @message_rule.destroy
      Messages::Reclassifier.call(allowed_params[:message])
    end
```

It returns me this error:

```
Failures:

  1) MessageRulesController#destroy When the message_rule has been destroyed classifies the messages
     Failure/Error: expect(Messages::Reclassifier).to have_received(:call)

       (Messages::Reclassifier (class)).call(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/controllers/message_rules_controller_spec.rb:108:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the spec:

```
describe '#destroy' do
    let(:message_rule) { build_stubbed(:message_rule) }

    before do
      allow(Messages::Reclassifier).to receive(:call)

      allow(MessageRule).to receive(:find).
        with(message_rule.id.to_s).
        and_return(message_rule)
    end

    subject(:destroy) { delete :destroy, params: { id: message_rule.id } }

    context 'When the message_rule has been destroyed' do
      before { allow(message_rule).to receive(:destroy).and_return(true) }

      it 'classifies the messages' do
        destroy

        expect(Messages::Reclassifier).to have_received(:call)
      end
    end

    context 'When the message_rule couldn\'t be destroyed' do
      before { allow(message_rule).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false) }

      it 'does not reclassify the messages' do
        destroy

        expect(Messages::Reclassifier).not_to have_received(:call)
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing in the specs? I am unexperienced with RSpec so I am having a hard time understanding this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating that Rspec expected `Messages::Reclassifier` to call the method `call`, but the method was not called. This means that something is preventing the method call from happening.  You seem to have the method stub set up correctly.

Since you are stubbing `Messages::Reclassifier#call` without the parameter option, it should not matter to Rspec whether or not you are passing in a parameter to `Messages::Reclassifier#call`. But it would matter if the `allowed_params[:message]` parameter is causing something like an exception.

Can you provide the entire controller class or at least all code that pertains to the "destroy" action?

Comment: Since you mentioned that the `allowed_params[:message]` seemed to be causing some kind of problems, I decided to experiment with it and what happens is that, since the `allowed_params` only sends params through requisitions and the destroy action wasn't sending anything to the requisition, so I replaced it with `@message_rule.message` and it worked just fine!